# Why is the sweave file extension 'rnw'?

Tags: r, sweave

What does it stand for?  I searched around for awhile, and there are a lot of web pages describing what a sweave file is, but not why the letters "rnw" were chosen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (while interesting) it's about the etymology of a file extension, not about programming *per se*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It stands for R NoWeb I believe

Comment: Verified, https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/software/Rnoweb/Rnoweb-guide.pdf

Comment: See the Sweave manual which refers to noweb syntax at one point: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/doc/Sweave.pdf  Noweb was a literate programming tool not specifically related to R whose syntax R adopted.  Noweb includes noweb and noweave tools (and others).  See: https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/ .